# concatenate children values in javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am trying to concatenate the values of the `li` children but it doesn't seem to be working for me. I want to upload the contacts that I accessed using the remote server for which I'm trying to concatenate all the `li` elements to a string. This is my code:

```
var list = document.getElementById('list');
var list_items = list.getElementsByTagName("li");
var temp="";
for (var i=0; i<list_items.length ; i++){
    for (var j=0; j<=list_items[i].childElementCount ; j++){
        temp+=list_items[i].children[j].textContent;
    }
    var modurl = url + "?name=" +temp;
    alert(modurl);
    temp="";
    ajax.open("GET", modurl, true);
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
            if(ajax.status == 200) {
                alert('Saved');
            }
        }
    };
}
ajax.send(null);
```

Comment: What's "not working" exactly? Maybe a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would help

Comment: the for loops are not working,if i comment them out , the code works fine

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @NidaZehra.  When asking questions, it is best if you give as much detail as you possibly can.  ***Not Working*** is the least useful description you give.  It is best if you explain what you *expect* to happen and what *is* happening.